# Can I use an ObservedObject inside a Coordinator?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a MapView using MKMapView, and I have a HomeView which shows the MapView and ResultsCarouselView (for now just replacing it with Circle for ease).

If I have an observable object to manage the state for this HomeView, is it possible to use this from the coordinator?  For example, anything I call from HomeState in the coordinator does not update HomeView:

MapCoordinator

```
final class MapCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
  @ObservedObject var homeState = HomeState()

  // other code, init, etc.

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    self.homeState.setUserLocated(true)
  }
}
```

HomeState:

```
class HomeState: NSObject, ObservableObject {
  @Published var userLocated = false

  func setUserLocated(_ value: Bool) {
    self.userLocated = value // debugger comes here, but is this another instance or something?
  }
}
```

HomeView:

```
struct HomeView: View {
  @ObservedObject var homeState = HomeState()
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      MapView()

      if (homeState.userLocated) {
         Circle()   // this doesn't show up
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
@StateObject var homeState = HomeState()

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {

}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var parent: MapView

    init(_ parent: MapView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        self.parent.homeState.setUserLocated(true)
    }
}
}
```

You use the `parent` variable in the `Coordinator` to modify any `@State` or `@ObservableObject` such as your `HomeState @ObservedObject`